# Perforce auto sync

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I work in a large evolving code base and use perforce to manage it. The problem is that I need to update it everyday and it takes a long time to do it. I am looking for ways to automate this process.

I first thought of writing an script and make it a scheduled task. I could not do it since running "p4 sync" gives me "p4 protect" related error. I don't have, and will not get, admin rights to server so I can't add myself to the protect table.

Since I can sync through P4V - perforce UI- I guess there should be a way to achieve this through custom tools or something similar.

Can you guys please provide pointers on how to approach this problem or if there is already a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

If 'p4 sync' gets a protect error in your script, but not when you use P4V, you most likely have the wrong environment in your script. P4PORT, P4USER, and P4CLIENT need to have the exact same settings in our script as they do in your P4V connection.